# calling function or procedure within same package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, package

Can I call a function or procedure by using package name, if they are defined in the same package?

Comment: Why not try it yourself?  As I remember - yes, you can use `<package name>.<procedure/function name>` though it's unnecessary within the same package.  But it has to come after the function/proc (top to bottom) for compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this will be helpful for you.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg10pck.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can call it using procedure name, for your help see the link
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7452431376537